# webdatarocks conditional formatting on percent fields

Tags: webdatarocks

Having a problem with WebDataRocks conditional formatting.

I have a field which is formatted as a %.

I wish to colour code the field red if > 100%. I have values in the field that are over 100%.

I have tried to use the conditional formatting options in the tool bar but this does not colour code the text (still remain black).

If you look at the attached image, you can see I have values that are over 100% and yet no formatting is applied.

[conditional formatting issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XvFu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you configure a field to be formatted as a percentage, the displayed value is multiplied by 100 (e.g., `0.1` becomes `10`). However, the conditional formatting is based on the actual underlying data, not the visual representation.

So, if you want the `> 100%` values to be formatted, base the formatting on the "Greater than 1" formula.

Here's a sample illustrating this: https://codepen.io/mhalaida/pen/eYWExjg.